# Jenkins pipeline if else not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am creating a sample jenkins pipeline, here is the code.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    stages {    
        stage('test') { 
            steps { 
                sh 'echo hello'
            }            
        }
        stage('test1') { 
            steps { 
                sh 'echo $TEST'
            }            
        }
        stage('test3') {
            if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
                echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
            } else {
                echo 'I execute elsewhere'
            }                        
        }        
    }
}
```

this pipeline fails with following error logs

```
Started by user admin
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 15: Not a valid stage section definition: "if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
                echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
            } else {
                echo 'I execute elsewhere'
            }". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 15, column 9.
           stage('test3') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 15: Nothing to execute within stage "test3" @ line 15, column 9.
           stage('test3') {
           ^
```

But when i execute the following example [from this url](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-steps), it executes successfully and print the else part.

```
node {
    stage('Example') {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
        } else {
            echo 'I execute elsewhere'
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference i can see is that in the working example there is no `stages` but in my case it has.

What is wrong here, can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

your first try is using declarative pipelines, and the second working one is using scripted pipelines. you need to enclose steps in a steps declaration, and you can't use `if` as a top-level step in declarative, so you need to wrap it in a `script` step. here's a working declarative version:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo hello'
            }
        }
        stage('test1') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo $TEST'
            }
        }
        stage('test3') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
                        echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
                    } else {
                        echo 'I execute elsewhere'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can simplify this and potentially avoid the if statement (as long as you don't need the else) by using "when". See "when directive" at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/. you can also validate jenkinsfiles using the jenkins rest api. it's super sweet. have fun with declarative pipelines in jenkins!

Comment: I'm not sure if you will read this after so many years. In the above example can we use a variable instead of an environment variable. In my declarative pipeline, I create a variable DO_BUILD=sh(...), here DO_BUILD will have a 1 or 0 based on my shell command. And now, I want to use DO_BUILD in the if (${DO_BUILD} == '1') statement, and it doesn't work and it throws error that $ is not DSL function.

Comment: You should ask a new question in this case so you can provide enough context for someone to answer your question and for other people with a similar issue to find it. You might try wrapping the dollar expression in double quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50288263/6090676.

Answer (score 51):

It requires a bit of rearranging, but `when` does a good job to replace conditionals above. Here's the example from above written using the declarative syntax. Note that `test3` stage is now two different stages. One that runs on the master branch and one that runs on anything else.

```
stage ('Test 3: Master') {
    when { branch 'master' }
    steps { 
        echo 'I only execute on the master branch.' 
    }
}

stage ('Test 3: Dev') {
    when { not { branch 'master' } }
    steps {
        echo 'I execute on non-master branches.'
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution rather then using if else when there is not so much complexity! Ty!

Comment: With 'when' condition, you are creating condition for complete stage, if it is false then complete stage will be skipped, and in case of 'if else', you still can execute 1 part of the script within the stage it will not be skipped.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to create a condition to execute only a stage based on expression you can use keyword `when`

```
stage ('test3'){
    when { expression { return env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'} }
    steps {
           echo 'I only execute on the master branch.'
          }
    }
}
```

With the `expression` key word you can add any condition.

e.g. if stage is dependent on generated file in workspace.

```
stage ('File Dependent stage'){
 when { expression { return fileExists ('myfile') } }
    steps {
           echo "file exists"
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
        if ( params.build_deploy == '1' ) {
            println "build_deploy 是 ${params.build_deploy}"
              jobB = build job: 'k8s-core-user_deploy', propagate: false, wait: true, parameters: [
                         string(name:'environment', value: "${params.environment}"),
                         string(name:'branch_name', value: "${params.branch_name}"),
                         string(name:'service_name', value: "${params.service_name}"),                      
                     ]
            println jobB.getResult()
        }
```

Comment: You can always delete it to regain rep, mate:)