# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps

Tags: jenkins

I have the following dsl

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'test'
    }
    parameters {        
        booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'This is a Release build', name: 'isRelease')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                 script {
                     if (${params.isRelease}) {
                          echo("This is a release")
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps
```

What I am doing wrong? I am using

- Jenkins 2.89.4
- Job DSL 1.68
- Pipeline Job 2.20
- Pipeline: API 2.27
- Pipeline: Basic Steps 2.7
- Pipeline: Build Steps 2.7
- Pipeline: Declarative 1.2.9

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok the answer can already be found in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854732/booleanparam-in-jenkins-dsl): Boolean parameter are in reality strings, so this works

```
if ("${params.isRelease}" == "true") {
    echo("This is a release")
}
```

Alternatively use the params-object

```
if (params.isRelease) {
    echo("This is a release")
}
```